# Why am I getting wrong answer for a problem from simple interest?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

**Problem** : 
The simple interest(S.I) rate offered by a bank is 4% in the first year. 
Staring from the second year, the simple interest rate offered by the bank is 1% more than the simple interest rate offered by the bank in the previous year.
After how many years will the total simple interest earned on the deposit be 30% more than the initial amount deposited?

**My** **Solution**:
S.I = P*N*R/100

For 1st year, S.I = P*1*4/100

For 2nd year, S.I = P*1*5/100

For 3rd year, S.I = P*1*6/100

.
.
.
For 13th year, S.I = P*1*16/100

Adding up all the S.I amounts from 1st year to 13th year gives 130*P/100 which is 30% more than P.

Hence the answer should be 13 according to me.

But the given answer is 16.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Your calculation looks solid to me.  Only thing I can imagine is that they are computing the rate of interest at the end...as you point out, that actually is $16$.

Comment: @lulu What do you mean by computing the rate of interest at the end? What is that approach?

Comment: All I meant was that the only $16$ I can see anywhere in the picture is the interest rate in the final year.  Of course, that's a big stretch from the phrasing you used.

Comment: 30 = 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = five years